# Eclipse, java project with linked source. Classpath fail

Tags: eclipse, junit, classpath

I'm using Eclipse to create a Java project. The problem is:

1. When source folders are inside the
   project folder, I can correctly run
   junit tests from elipse.
2. When source
       folders are outside the project
       folder (liked source folders) my
       junit tests are failed.

The reason is simple: junit tests are loading file using java.util.Properties and relative file path: **data/my_soft.properties**
where *data* is the name of the source folder.

In the case #**1** file *my_soft.properties* is on the classpath and can be seen by test classes.

In the case #**2** file *my_soft.properties* is not located, tests are failed.

I've wrote ant script to run tests, but I would like to know, is it possible to fix Eclipse? I would like to use Eclipse for debugging, it's more comfortable. And  I don't what to create a project each time. I just want to link sources and run tests.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading a file from the *source* directory then it isn't a *classpath* problem - unless you mean to include the source directory in your classpath. Try loading files off the classpath instead.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to amend the classpath your tests run with.  Highlight the tests and go Run on the toolbar.  Select run from the dropdown menu.  Now in the Classpath tab you can add in your source folder so the properties file can be found. (click Advanced button to be able to add a Folder).

Answer (score 0):

Under Project Properties/Java Build Path... you can specify an external folder to include in your classpath.  I think if you add the directory with the properties file there, you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the folder with the properties to the classpath for the run configuration for your tests. In under run configurations select the appropriate one, go into the classpath tab, then click Advanced and add the folder that contains your data folder.